# Percorrer JsonObject Android

Tags: android

Como percorrer um array de object da forma q eu consiga pegar os dados?

```
    {"number1":"value1", "number2":"value2", "number3":"value3"} 

  for (int c = 0; c < jsonObject.length(); c++) {

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, na verdade esse valor é um [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html). Um *Array de Objeto* seria algo como:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[];
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>;
/* etc */
```

Voltando ao assunto, você pode capturar as `keys`. Essa captura te retornar um [Iterator](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Iterator.html).

Com esse *Iterator* você poderá percorrer todas as `keys` e assim capturar os valores através de um `while` ou `do..while`

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject("{\"number1\":\"value1\", \"number2\":\"value2\", \"number3\":\"value3\"} ");
Iterator<String> keys = j.keys();

// Verifica se há mais alguma key
while (keys.hasNext() {
    // Captura a key e seu valor; e avança para a próxima
    System.out.println( j.get( keys.next() ).toString() );
}
```

Ou você pode utilizar o `for`

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject("{\"number1\":\"value1\", \"number2\":\"value2\", \"number3\":\"value3\"} ");

for ( Iterator<String> Keys = j.keys(); Keys.hasNext(); ) {
    System.out.println( j.get( Keys.next() ).toString() );
}
```

Comment: Funcionou cara !!  Muito obrigado